# javascript cut the text before specific words

Tags: javascript

I have large text like `his is a sample text to illustrate my scenario text=info id=2342` now from all of them I want to keep only 2432, that means anything after `id=` which is `2342` in this example. I have tried

```
let text = "his is a sample text to illustrate my scenario text=info id=2342"

text.substr(0, text.indexOf("id="));
```

but it does not work, I want to get everything after id= and remove everything  before it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will output everything after the last `=` char.

```js
let text = "his is a sample text to illustrate my scenario text=info id=2342"

let result = text.split("=").reverse()[0];

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```js
let text = "his is a sample text to illustrate my scenario text=info id=2342";
let id = text.substring(text.indexOf("id=")+3);
console.log(id);
```

Answer (score 2):

You may do the trick with RegExp:

```js
const str = "his is a sample text to illustrate my scenario text=info id=2342",

      id = str.match(/id=(\d+)/)[1]
      
console.log(id)
```